# Corner detection algorithm gives very high value for slanted edges?

Tags: python, computer-vision, gradient, edge-detection, corner-detection

I have tried implementing a basic version of shi-tomasi corner detection algorithm. The algorithm works fine for corners but I came across a strange issue that the algorithm also gives high values for slanted(titled) edges.

Here's what i did

- Took gray scale image
- computer dx, and dy of the image by convolving it with sobel_x and sobel_y
- Took a 3 size window and moved it across the image to compute the sum of the elements in the window.
- computed sum of the window elements from the dy image and sum of window elements from the dx image and saved it in sum_xx and sum_yy.
- created a new image (call it `result`) where that pixel for which the window sum was computed was replaced with `min(sum_xx, sum_yy)` as shi-tomasi algorithm requires.

I expected it to give maximum value for corners where dx and dy both are high, but i found it giving high values even for titled edges.

Here are the some outputs of the image i received: 
[image]

Result:
[image]

so far so good, corners have high values.

Another Image:
[image]

Result:
[image]

Here's where the problem lies. edges have high values which is not expected by the algorithm. I can't fathom how can edges have high values for both x and y gradients (sobel being close approximation of gradient).

I would like to ask your help, if you can help me fix this issue for edges. I am open to any suggestions and ideas .

Here's my code (if it helps):

```py
def st(image, w_size):
    v = []
    dy, dx = sy(image), sx(image)

    dy = dy**2
    dx = dx**2
    dxdy = dx*dy

    dx = cv2.GaussianBlur(dx, (3,3), cv2.BORDER_DEFAULT)
    dy = cv2.GaussianBlur(dy, (3,3), cv2.BORDER_DEFAULT)
    dxdy = cv2.GaussianBlur(dxdy, (3,3), cv2.BORDER_DEFAULT)

    ofset = int(w_size/2)
    for y in range(ofset, image.shape[0]-ofset):
        for x in range(ofset, image.shape[1]-ofset):

            s_y = y - ofset
            e_y = y + ofset + 1

            s_x = x - ofset
            e_x = x + ofset + 1

            w_Ixx = dx[s_y: e_y, s_x: e_x]
            w_Iyy = dy[s_y: e_y, s_x: e_x]
            w_Ixy = dxdy[s_y: e_y, s_x: e_x]

            sum_xx = w_Ixx.sum()
            sum_yy = w_Iyy.sum()
            sum_xy = w_Ixy.sum()
            #sum_r = w_r.sum()

            m = np.matrix([[sum_xx, sum_xy],
                         [sum_xy, sum_yy]])

            eg = np.linalg.eigvals(m)

            v.append((min(eg[0], eg[1]), y, x))
    return v

def sy(img):
    t = cv2.Sobel(img,cv2.CV_8U,0,1,ksize=3)
    return t
def sx(img):
    t = cv2.Sobel(img,cv2.CV_8U,1,0,ksize=3)
    return t
```

Comment: take the absolute values of `dx` and `dy`

Comment: In terms of a "bucket of gradients" what is the difference between a 45deg edge and a corner? they both have strong gradients in both x-direction and y-direction. How do you expect your method to distinguish between them?

Comment: A good point to consider, but how should we find corners then ?

Comment: BTW, try and rotate the first image by 45 degrees and apply your filter - you should get significantly different results.

Comment: Please don't edit your question in this way, it invalidates the answers below. Instead, add an answer of your own with your improved code. By the way, in `cv2.GaussianBlur` you should set the `sigmaX` parameter, and let the `ksize` argument be computed from that. A 3x3 Gaussian is typically not big enough for this application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You misunderstood the [Shi-Tomasi method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corner_detection#The_Harris_&_Stephens_/_Shi%E2%80%93Tomasi_corner_detection_algorithms). You are computing the two derivatives `dx` and `dy`, locally averaging them (the sum is different from the local average by a constant factor which we can ignore), and then taking the lowest value. The Shi-Tomasi equation refers to the [Structure Tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_tensor), it uses the lowest of the two eigenvalues of this matrix.

The Structure tensor is a matrix formed by the outer product of the gradient with itself, and then smoothed:

```
[ smooth(dx*dx)  smooth(dx*dy) ]
[ smooth(dx*dy)  smooth(dy*dy) ]
```

That is, we take the x-derivative `dx` and the y-derivative `dy`, form the three images `dx*dx`, `dy*dy` and `dx*dy`, and smooth these three images. Now for each pixel we have three values that together form a symmetric matrix. This is called the structure tensor.

The eigenvalues of this structure tensor say something about the local edges. If both are small, there are no edges in the neighborhood. If one is large, then there's a single edge direction in the local neighborhood. If both are large, there's something more complex going on, likely a corner. The larger the smoothing window, the larger the local neighborhood we're examining. It is important to select a neighborhood size that matches the size of the structure we're looking at.

The eigenvectors of the structure tensor say something about the orientation of the local structure. If there's an edge (one eigenvalue is large), then the corresponding eigenvector will be the normal to this edge.

Shi-Tomasi uses the smallest of the two eigenvalues. If the smallest of the two eigenvalues is large, then there's something more complex than an edge going on in the local neighborhood.

The Harris corner detector also uses the Structure tensor, but it combines the determinant and trace obtain a similar result with less computational cost. Shi-Tomasi is better but more expensive to compute because the eigenvalue computation requires the computation of square roots. The Harris detector is an approximation to the Shi-Tomasi detector.

Here is a comparison on Shi-Tomasi (top) and Harris (bottom). I've clipped both to half their max value, as the max values happen in the text area and this lets us see the weaker responses to relevant corners better. As you can see, Shi-Tomasi has a more uniform response to all the corners in the image.

[image: Shi-Tomasi result]

[image: Harris result]

For both of these, I've used a Gaussian window with sigma=2 for the local averaging (which, using a cutoff of 3 sigma, leads to a 13x13 averaging window).

---

Looking at your updated code, I see several issues. I've annotated these with comments here:

```py
def st(image, w_size):
    v = []
    dy, dx = sy(image), sx(image)

    dy = dy**2
    dx = dx**2
    dxdy = dx*dy
    # Here you have dxdy=dx**2 * dy**2, because dx and dy were changed
    # in the lines above.

    dx = cv2.GaussianBlur(dx, (3,3), cv2.BORDER_DEFAULT)
    dy = cv2.GaussianBlur(dy, (3,3), cv2.BORDER_DEFAULT)
    dxdy = cv2.GaussianBlur(dxdy, (3,3), cv2.BORDER_DEFAULT)
    # Gaussian blur size should be indicated with the sigma of the Gaussian,
    # not with the size of the kernel. A 3x3 kernel corresponds, in OpenCV,
    # to a Gaussian with sigma = 0.8, which is way too small. Use sigma=2.

    ofset = int(w_size/2)
    for y in range(ofset, image.shape[0]-ofset):
        for x in range(ofset, image.shape[1]-ofset):

            s_y = y - ofset
            e_y = y + ofset + 1

            s_x = x - ofset
            e_x = x + ofset + 1

            w_Ixx = dx[s_y: e_y, s_x: e_x]
            w_Iyy = dy[s_y: e_y, s_x: e_x]
            w_Ixy = dxdy[s_y: e_y, s_x: e_x]

            sum_xx = w_Ixx.sum()
            sum_yy = w_Iyy.sum()
            sum_xy = w_Ixy.sum()
            # We've already done the local averaging using GaussianBlur,
            # this summing is now no longer necessary.

            m = np.matrix([[sum_xx, sum_xy],
                         [sum_xy, sum_yy]])

            eg = np.linalg.eigvals(m)

            v.append((min(eg[0], eg[1]), y, x))
    return v

def sy(img):
    t = cv2.Sobel(img,cv2.CV_8U,0,1,ksize=3)
    # The output of Sobel has positive and negative values. By writing it
    # into a 8-bit unsigned integer array, you lose all these negative
    # values, they become 0. This is half your edges that you lose!
    return t
def sx(img):
    t = cv2.Sobel(img,cv2.CV_8U,1,0,ksize=3)
    return t
```

This is how I modified your code:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

def st(image):
    dy, dx = sy(image), sx(image)
    dxdx = cv2.GaussianBlur(dx**2, ksize = None, sigmaX=2)
    dydy = cv2.GaussianBlur(dy**2, ksize = None, sigmaX=2)
    dxdy = cv2.GaussianBlur(dx*dy, ksize = None, sigmaX=2)
    for y in range(image.shape[0]):
        for x in range(image.shape[1]):
            m = np.matrix([[dxdx[y,x], dxdy[y,x]],
                           [dxdy[y,x], dydy[y,x]]])
            eg = np.linalg.eigvals(m)
            image[y,x] = min(eg[0], eg[1])  # Write into the input image.
                                            # Better would be to create a new
                                            # array as output. Make sure it is
                                            # a floating-point type!

def sy(img):
    t = cv2.Sobel(img,cv2.CV_32F,0,1,ksize=3)
    return t

def sx(img):
    t = cv2.Sobel(img,cv2.CV_32F,1,0,ksize=3)
    return t

image = cv2.imread('fu4r5.png', 0)
output = image.astype(np.float32)  # I'm writing the result of the detector in here
st(output)
pp.imshow(output); pp.show()
```

Comment: Your answer is wonderful. I just need to ask 2 things, I'm not sure what do you mean by smoothing the image. Do you mean blurring the image or do you mean simply computing the sum of dx^2 and dy^2 ?

The documentation of harris corners says 
`matrix = w(x,y) [ dx^2     dx.dy]
                          [ dx.dy    dy^2] `
what is w(x,y) here ?

Comment: The summing in a local window that you do is equivalent to applying a blurring filter (which computes the local mean instead of the sum, these just differ by a constant factor). The `w` in your reference is a local window function. It can be, for example, 1 in the region `[s_y: e_y, s_x: e_x]` and zero outside, as you do in your summing function, or it can be a set of weights for weighted averaging. Gaussian weights are very common here, and lead to very good results. The `w` in that case is equivalent to applying a Gaussian smoothing to each of the components of the matrix. @Syed

Comment: so once i have this matrix:

[ dx^2   dx.dy ]

[ dx.dy  dy^2  ]

I have to blur it (let's call the blur version as r). and then compute the eigen values from the r matrix.

Right?

Comment: @Syed: Yes. Here, `dx^2` is an image, `dx.dy` is an image, and `dy^2` is an image. Each of these you need to blur. Then you need to, for each pixel, get one value from each of these images, form your matrix, and compute its eigenvalues. This leads to the corniness measure for that one pixel.

Comment: I've updated the code as you mentioned, please have a look at `st(..)` function in the question. I did as you said but the results seem to be the same. I am getting high value for edges. I might have misunderstood something . 
Can you identify what's wrong. I tried to do exactly as you said.`v` in code represents an array of vectors  where each vector is `[min(eigen_1, eigen_2), y_value, x_value]`

Comment: @Syed: I also wrote this in a comment to the question: in `cv2.GaussianBlur` you should set the `sigmaX` parameter, and let the `ksize` argument be computed from that (i.e. don't provide it yourself). A 3x3 Gaussian is typically not big enough for this application. Set `sigmaX` to 2, it will lead to a `ksize` of at least 9x9 or hopefully larger.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215692/discussion-between-syed-hissaan-and-cris-luengo).

Comment: I tried with this, but nothing changed `cv2.GaussianBlur(img, ksize = None, sigmaX=2)`

Comment: @Syed: I've updated the answer with comments on your code and a corrected version.

Comment: I have no words to thank you for such an amazing explanation and continually answering my questions. 
Can i make your acquaintance on another forum, possibly linked-in or gmail ?

Comment: I'm on LinkedIn, feel free to connect. But please don't see that as a short-cut to asking questions. I'd rather answer them here where more people can benefit. :)

Comment: After you pointed out the mistakes, the code runs as expected and detects corner points. There is something i would like to ask at this point, many corner points lie too close to each other. Is there an intuitive way to consider only some out of all the closely lying corner points. Something similar to python version of `good_features_to_track(...)`

Comment: @Syed: not sure what the problem is. Maybe you are thresholding the result and finding many pixels set for the same corner? You need to find local maxima of the cornerness image, not just threshold. If the problem is an image with many corners close together, you could increase the sigma of the smoothing, which will make it so you can detect fewer points. The other option is to iterate through neighboring corners and, if they’re close together, remove the less strong one.

Answer (score 0):

If you are after corners, why don't you look at the [Harris](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_features_harris/py_features_harris.html) corner detection?
This detector does not look only at the first derivatives, but also at the second derivatives and how they are arranged in the loca neighborhood.

```py
ans = cv2.cornerHarris(np.float32(gray)/255., 2, 3, 0.03)
```

looking at pixels with `ans > 0.001`:
[image]
As you can see, most of the corners were detected, but not the slanted edges.
You might need to play a bit with the parameters of the Harris detector to get better results.

I strongly recommend that you read the explanation and rationale behind this detector and how it is able to robustly distinguish between corners and slanted edges. Make sure you understand how this is different than the method you posted.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I went through the theory and wanted to implement one myself to find if i have understood it right. The thing that bothers me is that i have tried to do exactly as the theory mentioned, however i came across an issue with slanted edges. 
I wonder how the harris corner work on the backend and how they get over with slanted edges ?
Do you have any idea ?

Comment: @SyedHissaan the Harris detector does not work in the same way as your algorithm. It looks at higher order information. Please read carefully the documentation

Comment: I might have missed something though i went through it. I actually wanted it work like shi-tomasi algorithm. Can you suggest a more suitable way to find corner points. Currently i'm using `min(sum_dx_in_wind, sum_dy_in_wind)` and then using the max n values as corners

Comment: that seems the thing i have been missing, i would try to look up for it

Comment: The Harris corner detector does **not** use second order derivatives. It uses first order derivatives just like the Shi-Tomasi detector (through the structure tensor). It just does something slightly different with the structure tensor.