# How to implement the Shi-Tomasi method without use of GoodFeatures to track?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I am trying to implement a version of Shi-Tomasi without using the GoodFeaturesToTrack() function. How do I do this using non-local maximum supression? Code attached if it helps: Trying to save the location of each max x,each max y , and Q into the array results

```
def nonMaximalSupress(image,NHoodSize):
#
dX = NHoodSize
dY = NHoodSize
M, N = image.shape
for x in range(0,M-dX+1):
    for y in range(0,N-dY+1):
        window = image[x:x+dX, y:y+dY]
        if np.sum(window)==0:
            localMax=0
        else:
            localMax = np.amax(window)
        maxCoord = np.argmax(window)
        # zero all but the localMax in the window
        window[:] = 0
        window.flat[maxCoord] = localMax
return image
```

```
################################
NUMRESULTS = 5000
def detectKeypoints(img, alpha):
    I = np.float32(img)
    results = np.zeros( (NUMRESULTS,3), dtype = float)

    sigma = float(1.414)
    ksize = int(1 + np.sqrt(-2*sigma**2*np.log(0.005)))

    #############my code here############
    # Shi-Tomasi Method 

    # Find the X and Y gradient components using Sobel kernels
    Ix = cv2.Sobel(I, cv2.CV_64F,1,0,ksize)
    Iy = cv2.Sobel(I,cv2.CV_64F,0,1,ksize)

    # components of the local structure matrix
    A = np.square(Ix)
    B = np.square(Iy)
    C = np.multiply(Ix,Iy)

    M = [[A,C], # local structure matrix 
         [C,B]] 

    # get a Gaussian kernel for set ksize and signma value
    gauss = cv2.getGaussianKernel(ksize,sigma)

    # smooth individual components of the local structure matrix
    A_filter = cv2.filter2D(A, cv2.CV_64F, gauss)
    B_filter = cv2.filter2D(B, cv2.CV_64F, gauss)
    C_filter = cv2.filter2D(C, cv2.CV_64F, gauss)


    Q = 0
    yloc = 0
    xloc = 0
    for c in range(img.shape[0]):
        for r in range(img.shape[1]):

            M_bar = ([[A_filter[c,r], C_filter[c,r]],
                      [C_filter[c,r], B_filter[c,r]]])


            eg = np.linalg.eigvals(M_bar)
           #img[c,r] = min(eg[0], eg[1])
        Q = min(eg[0],eg[1])

        possible_corner_locations = nonMaximalSupress(img, ksize)

        for c1 in range(possible_corner_locations.shape[0]):
            for r1 in range(possible_corner_locations.shape[1]):
                if possible_corner_locations[c1,r1] != 0:
                    yloc = c1
                    xloc = r1
                    for i in range(NUMRESULTS):
                          results[i,0] = xloc
                           results[i,1] = yloc
                           results[i,2] = Q
                    else:
                        pass



    return results
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Corner detection algorithm gives very high value for slanted edges?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62298904/corner-detection-algorithm-gives-very-high-value-for-slanted-edges)

Comment: Sort of I see the corrected code on that question. How would I go about storing the min(eg[0],eg[1]) in a new vector and then store a the possible x location, y location, and that vector into a new result?

Comment: you need to compute that value for each pixel, that code produces an image. Now you need to find local maxima in that image: find pixels whose value is larger than those of its neighbors, and larger than some threshold that you pick. Those pixels you put into a list (x,y,value). This step has to be a separate loop through the image, you can't do it at the same time you compute the eigenvalues.

Comment: Could you possibly show me some code to go about doing that?

Comment: I'm sorry didn't mean it like that. I updated the post with the code I have. Can you explain where I might be going wrong?

Comment: I think something might have gone wrong with the indenting. In any case, in your non-max suppression I think you need to check if `maxCoord` is the center of the window or not. If it's not, don't set the whole window to zero. Because if the max happens at the edge of the window, it might not be an actual local max. Then you need to write the window back into your image.

Comment: Am I going about storing in the results variable correctly?